How to multiply dots with Young idempotents in the degenerate affine Hecke algebra (type A)
Let $\widehat{\cal H}_n$ be the type A degenerate affine Hecke algebra on $n$ strands, and let $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ be the dots. Inside of this algebra lies the algebra $\mathbb C S_n$, and the Young idempotents (one for each standard Young tableau of any shape) $e_T$ are certainly still idempotents inside $\widehat{\cal H}_n$. Let $T,S,R$ be standard Young tableaux of shapes $\lambda<\mu<\nu$ which form a ``tight'' chain in the dominance order poset (meaning you can't fit another partition in there). Generically let $P(x)$ denote a polynomial in dots in $\widehat{\cal H}_n$.
Question: Is there a ''good'' way to compute something like $e_T \cdot P(x) \cdot e_S \cdot Q(x) \cdot e_R$, i.e. find $F(x)$ such that $$e_T \cdot P(x) \cdot e_S \cdot Q(x) \cdot e_R=e_T \cdot F(x)\cdot e_R?$$ What is the most I can say about something like this? (My end goal is to get some type of manageable ''quadratic relations''; I don't have to be able to write them down explicitly necessarily, but of course the more I can say the better.) More generally anything about commuting dots past Young idempotents would be great.
Some further observations: because symmetric polynomials are central in the Hecke, if $f$ is symmetric, one has $e_T f e_S=e_T e_S f=0$, so it suffices to consider $P(x)$ in (polynomials) mod (positive degree symmetric polynomials), which has a basis given by Schubert polynomials. But this is not the same as multiplying Schubert polynomials because there is an extra idempotent $e_S$ in the middle.
Example: Let $n=3$. Let $T$ be the standard tableau for the column, $S$ be the standard (12,3) for the hook, and $R$ the standard for the row. If my calculations are correct, then $$e_T x_1 e_S x_1 e_R=-e_T x_1x_2 e_R.$$ Here $x_1$ and $x_1x_2$ happen to both be Schubert polynomials; they are $\mathfrak S_{s_1}$ and $\mathfrak S_{s_1s_2}$. Another example is
$$e_T x_1 e_S x_2 e_R=e_T(x_1^2+x_1x_2)e_R.$$
I was not able to divine any pattern from these examples. Another example, not entirely related, is that $e_T x_1 e_R=0$, which I believe must be a general phenomenon ($T$ and $R$ are ''too far apart'').
Where I am coming from: For representation theoretic reasons, I have a subalgebra of the Hecke, and I am expecting it to 1. have a grading 2. be one-generated in this grading 3. be quadratic and 4. be Koszul. Once I can say something about how dots commute past the middle Young idempotent in this ''idempotent sandwich'' I described above (commuting e.g. $P$ past $e_S$ in $e_T P e_S Q e_R$) I expect to be able to prove Koszulity without too much difficulty.
